# Random Image slideshow with fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have images that I'd like to rotate in an automatic random slideshow.  I want each to fade in and out.  Here's my HTML:

```
<center><div>
  <img class="mySlides" id="div2" src="animals.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
  <img class="mySlides" id="div2" src="fly.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
  <img class="mySlides" id="div2" src="three.jpg" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
</div></center>
```

And here's my script:

```
<script>

var slideIndex = 0;
 carousel();

function carousel() {

        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length());
        $(x).fadeIn("slow");

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }

        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 

        setTimeout(function () { // Change image every 4 seconds
        $(x).fadeOut("slow");
        }, 4000);
    }

</script>
```

Only the first image is loading in and I have no idea why.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: you need to call carousel() again in your timeout

Comment: @derelict Okay, sou should that line look like this: }, 4000, carousel()); ?  Because when I do that, after the first picture fades out, all three appear and stay there.

Answer (score 1):

your carousel() function only provides one iteration of your slideshow.  you can try simply adding a call to carousel in your timeout as such:

```
setTimeout(function () { // Change image every 4 seconds
    $(x).fadeOut("slow", function() { 
        carousel(); 
    });
}, 4000);
```

notice that i'm calling an anonymous function in the 'callback' slot of the 'fadeOut' function; this ensures your next 'carousel()' run will happen after the old image fades out.  to have both fades occur simultaneously, simply skip the callback:

```
setTimeout(function () { // Change image every 4 seconds
    $(x).fadeOut("slow");
    carousel(); 
}, 4000);
```

this will start the next fade in as the old image is fading out.

Comment: Okay, but now the pictures are fading in and out very quickly.  All three pictures are on the page at the same time now as well.

Comment: how quickly is 'very quickly'?  try adjusting your 4000ms timeout timer

Comment: One of them was flickering several times a second.  The others were slower, but below it.  I only want one image at a time.

Comment: something is calling your carousel function much faster than once every 4000ms then... is there anything else initiating calls to your carousel() function?  also, might be good to take this to chat so not to fill the comments